# How to run graphical app in background mode?

Tags: background-process

How to run example gedit without window (background mode)?

Comment: And what will gedit without a window?

Comment: Why do you want to run Gedit without it opening a window? Gedit is literally a graphical text editor, and that's it. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Gedit is a graphical application - as far as I know it can only run inside a window.

Comment: If you're looking for a CLI app, try Nano

Comment: Do you mean as a `daemon`? The man page for gedit makes no reference to that possibility.

Comment: Ok.  Judging by the fact my answer was accepted, I'm assuming that "without window" was a red herring, and the OP means "from the command line".  My guess is that this is an error in translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running an app from the command-line, it runs in "foreground" mode and occupies the current shell until it ends.

```
$gedit myfile
```

To put a currently-running "foreground" app into the background, (i.e. The window still runs, but the shell returns) you first have to *pause* the process by pressing the key combination CTRL+z.

This will tell you it has paused the process and return you to a command prompt:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gedit
$
```

At this point, gedit will be frozen because it is paused.  You can see the paused process by calling `jobs`.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 gedit
```

And you can then put the process into the background by calling `bg %1` (or just `bg` since it assumes the most recent process)

```
$ bg
[1]+ gedit &
$
```

As you see, gedit is now unfrozen, and the '&' indicates that it's running in the background.

You can shortcut all this messing about by simply adding the '&' to the end of the command you are calling, and it will return the new Process ID, e.g.

```
$ gedit myfile &
[1] 12882
$
```

For more information on process management, you might want to read one of the many excellent guides on the internet, such as this one: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0100.php

Comment: It's also important to note that, in the case of gedit and others, if you background gedit and then call it again, it will use the currently-running backgrounded process instead of creating a new one.